# Synchronous xhr in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to make a synchronous xhr call from flash?
How do you do this in actionscript?

Answer (score 1):

Two condition must hold true:

1. You must show no mercy to the users of your program. (On some very common operating system this will put all processes to a full stop and the fan on the CPU will propel the tower slowly away from the place it was in).
2. Flash should be allowed to call JavaScript.

Certain limitations apply: plain binary data may arrive garbled because JavaScript has no tools to deal with it.

If neither scares you - use ExternalInterface to call XMLHttpRequest synchronously.

Comment: LOL! But you should probably include a "Just don't." somewhere, just to be absolutely clear ;)

Comment: "On some very common operating system this will put all processes to a full stop" — like MS DOS? I guess Flash could be able to stale the GUI of some browsers, but if your OS supports preemption (it does), you won't "put all processes to a full stop" …

Comment: @Kay a single process with highest priority? - you may as well wait for the system to try to suspend it for about two minutes - it could be faster to just restart. Some very common operating system likes to be restarted, so it sounds like a fair deal :) So, from user's perspective unresponsive for long time = stale. Also, I think you could figure on your own that wasn't supposed to be a precise definition of what is going to happen. Well, I hope so...